# "Shrinking" droplists on comboboxes, not letting users choose the same answer in to or more comboboxes, using a form with VBA coding in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Inside a form I have 5 comboboxes with a same rowsource. Currently you can select the same option for all 5 comboboxes if you want. What I need is, whenever you select one option in a combobox, in the next combobox show the same list from the rowsource but excluding the options already selected in previous comboboxes. This way the droplist will continue shrinking while you keep selecting options, not allowing the user to repeat the same option in 2 or more comboboxes.

I manage to make it work on a worksheet with formulas and data validation, but no clue how to make it work using vba and comboboxes on an userform.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1t4yl7P7-9A

Literally this is what I need to do, but with a userform and VBA coding 
(watch the video to have a better Idea if my explanation is still not clear)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have tagged this question with *VBA*. Please, show the code you have tried, where are you stuck and so on.

Comment: When an item is selected, capture the items in current `Combobox` (possibly in an array), remove the selected item from the array and set the row source for other `Comboboxes` with that array

Comment: Welcome! Also, people may be voting you down because you need to show some effort.  Also, here is a link to [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following to achieve what you're looking for

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call UpdateComboBoxValues
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateComboBoxValues()
    Dim ComboValues As Variant, ComboBoxes As Variant
    Dim cBox

    ComboBoxes = Array(ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3)
    ComboValues = Array("w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5")

    For Each cBox In ComboBoxes
        If Not cBox.Value = vbNullString Then ComboValues = Filter(ComboValues, cBox.Value, False)
    Next cBox

    For Each cBox In ComboBoxes
        cBox.List = ComboValues
    Next cBox
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Call UpdateComboBoxValues
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Call UpdateComboBoxValues
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Call UpdateComboBoxValues
End Sub
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that update all `combobox` values.. even the one where the value was selected? hence removing the selected value from active `combobox`. Although OP hasn't specified if that's ok or not.. just a thought

Comment: You're right it would do, however I don't see that as being an issue for most things - the value is still there (it's selected) and would be there again once it is deselected

Comment: Fare enough. On a different note, what did you use to do the recording? I have never worked out how people do that :)

Comment: @Zac It's a really handy tool called [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/)

Comment: Brilliant!! Just what I needed, thanks Tom!